# Is there an Apple Visits Location Service equivalent?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-places-api, google-account, google-location-services

I'm looking to create an app for Android that checks a users location history to draw some conclusions of their daily life and identify behavioural patterns.

The Visits Location Service for IOS seems perfect for this kind of work as  it logs location history separately, and then allows apps to access that data, but I'm struggling to find an equivalent for Android. I've looked into different Google API's, but nothing seems to fit the description very well - ideally, I could use the data already gathered by Google Timeline in order to avoid having the application active all the time, but so far I haven't found any way to access that data.

So, is there any equivalent for Android?

Comment: Do you have a specific use case in mind? I have something in mind, but I'm not sure if it will help you achieve what you want.

Comment: What I was thinking about is the Google Awareness API https://developers.google.com/awareness/android-api/snapshot-api-overview . Let me know what you think

Comment: The Google Awareness API seems to definitely be a step in the right direction! Will be sure to check it out, thanks alot!